# Differences between Editor and Viewer in NSDocument

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

I have a `NSDocument` that acts as an editor for one of my document types and as a viewer for another.  Does Apple's default code lock the file for a viewer and/or do anything else to help the developer?  Or is editor-ness *vs.* viewer-ness something my type has to define and enforce manually?

Comment: I believe (but I'm not 100% sure) that the primary distinction is in how the file-format chooser in the open and save panels work.  Editor and Viewer let you open documents (of course), but only Editor formats appear in the list of file formats in the Save panel.